# Which supersymmetry principles make the axio-dilaton field in F-theory holomorphic?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, branes

I am following the lecture notes on F-theory by [T. Weigand](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.3497v2.pdf) . On page 7 he states that when considering F-theory as the strong coupling limit of type IIB orientifolds with D-branes, the axio-dilaton field defined on the coordinates perpendicular to the brane has to depend holomorphically on these coordinates.

My question is: what are these conditions? A reference would be greatly appreciated as well.